# 405 Error when exchanging auth token for access token

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have authenticated to Google Drive API and have received an authentication token

I then create my URI as follows

```
   AccessUri = new stringBuilder("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token")
   With AccessUri
                .AppendFormat("?code={0}", oAuth.UrlEncode(AccessToken)) 'Received in first part
                .AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", oAuth.UrlEncode(ConsumerKey)) 'Received from google API
                .AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", oAuth.UrlEncode(ConsumerSecret)) 'Received from google API
                .AppendFormat("&grant_type={0}", oAuth.UrlEncode("authorization_code"))
                .AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", oAuth.UrlEncode(RedirectURL)) 'using http:localhost/authorise.html
   End With
   dim uriAccess as uri = new uri(AccessUri.tostring)
```

If i paste this into the address bar I get Error 405 Method Not Allowed. If I send it as a request in VB.net I get the same error

DO i need to do anything in https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You will not have any luck with using this endpoint:

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token
```

to get a Google OAuth token. You should use Google's OAuth 2.0 service, not Dropbox's.